# JBoss Seam: How to Open jpa/hibernate session in view

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, seam2

There is a similar question for [Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139985/in-spring-with-jpa-hibernate-how-do-i-keep-a-session-open-to-avoid-lazy-initiali).

But what about JBoss Seam, I need a suggestion regarding the application I am developing.

If you need any specific version information, they are

- Seam 2.2
- JSF 1.2
- JPA 1 and Hibernate as persistence provider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the seam documentation related to persistence contexts.

http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/reference/en-US/html/persistence.html#persistence.seam-managed-persistence-contexts

Essentially, you register the persistence context with seam and inject the EntityManager into your bean. You can associate the context with a conversation to keep the session open across multiple requests by setting the flushMode in the @Begin annotation (@Begin and @End control conversations).