# Is there a solution to avoid LazyInitializationException

Tags: spring, hibernate, lazy-loading

I am using spring 3.2 spring security and hibernate 3.4.0.

When my user login I store a User in my custom principal.

Later in the application I want to access a collection associated to my User.
So I do :

```
User u = ((MyCustomPrincipal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUser();
u.getMyCollection();
```

and I am getting of course a LazyInitException.
So my temporary solution is to fetch again the user :

```
User u = ((MyCustomPrincipal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUser();
u = userDao.find(u.getId());
u.getMyCollection();
```

by doing this it works but I feel that it is not a very optimized solution because my User ows 4 collections, so I wil be forced to fetch my user from db multiple time in diffent place (in my custom authenticator, in an interceptor, in my controller...).

Is there a solution to this problem like a global transaction or something ?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Spring with jpa/hibernate, how do I keep a session open to avoid lazy initialization exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139985/in-spring-with-jpa-hibernate-how-do-i-keep-a-session-open-to-avoid-lazy-initial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When my user login I store a User in my custom principal

At that point in your login code where you fetch the user from the userDao for the first time, just add the `user.getMyCollection()` call. This will fetch the associated collection and store it in the user object. When you access it later through the `SecurityContextHolder`, the `LazyIntializationException` will not be thrown.

Comment: That is a terrible solution. It will hit a lazy connection each and every time, even it is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

You can try merging the detached user to the current session:

```
User u = ((MyCustomPrincipal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUser();
u = userDao.merge(u);
u.getMyCollection();
```

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.4/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#d0e891

Comment: just tried it works but I saw a select in the logs, so it is the same as what I am doing actually

Comment: You can load the user and their collections at the beginning with eager fetching. But I recommend you to store in the session a simple object (with the user id and other simple info) instead of the hibernate object (big and heavy). And not to be scary to ask to the DB when required